# Rails authlogic : How to make Levels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, access-levels

I followed this tutorial for setting [Autlogic up properly](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic). So, my site needs a form of level, like "Admin", "Moderator", "User", "Guest". So Admins can do everything, where Moderators may not can make site changes. And Users can't destroy, Update or Create.

Comment: Slighly offtopic, but consider giving Devise a look instead of using Authlogic. Even by using an older gem for rails 2, you will get a better service than with Autlogic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an authorization framework like [cancan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [declarative_authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) for that.

Comment: Just read about it.. My fail, sorry. Thank you for your help ;)!

Comment: Authlogic is only for authentication. You need an authorization framework to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my example project with Authlogic, Facebook Connect, declarative_authorization and user to user messaging.

http://github.com/jspooner/authlogic_cucumber_rspec_example